# Can yum be configured to import keys for non-Red Hat repositories?

Tags: yum, redhat-satellite

If I build a new RHEL server (whichever version, doesn't matter) and then attempt to install packages from either RHN or Satellite via `yum` I'm prompted to accept the RHN GPG key. In our case, this would be Satellite.

However, if I import my own packages to Satellite either by placing them in an existing Base channel or creating a new channel specifically for them, I'm not prompted to accept the key. The packages are signed and I've added the GPG key to Satellite.

Is there a way to get this prompt to show on custom channels or do I have no choice but to install the GPG key using `rpm --import`?

Answer (score 1):

After posting this I kept looking around. I did some searches for various strings and landed on [an identical question on the RHN community site](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1186393). One of the [comments](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1186393#comment-811553) explains why I have been unable to do what I want to do and, in turn, led to me solving the problem with some scripting.

The gist of it is that when I added the GPG Key URL to the Satellite channel I was using `http://satellite.example.com/pub/<key>`. Satellite will not allow this due to potential [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Instead, it only supports the `file///` URL construct. This tells yum to find the key on the local filesystem. Naturally this requires that the key be available locally.

I changed the GPG Key URL to point to the key located at `file///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/<key>`. I use `wget` to place the key in that location. Now `yum` asks if I wish to import the key. Once I enter `y` the key is added to my rpm key-chain and everything else completes appropriately.